# What does the perfect infinitive mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, infinitives, perfect-aspect, modality

I came across a sentence recently: *Before I turn 40, I want to have written a book.*

Could someone explain to me what does it actually mean?

I'd rather say: *Before I turn 40, I want to write a book.* but I'm not native speaker.

I understand the meaning of the perfect infinitive in sentences below:

*If I had known you were coming I would have baked a cake.*

*Someone must have broken the window and climbed in*

but I can't grasp the difference between:

*Before I turn 40, I want to have written a book* vs *Before I turn 40, I want to write a book*

Thanks for any help
Marcel

Comment: "*When I'm 40, I want to be able to look back on my life and be able to number among my achievements that I wrote a book*".

Comment: By the time I turn 40  I want to have written a book.

Comment: It's the same difference as that between *I wrote a book* and *I have written a book*. Basically, not much.

Comment: Comparing "Before I turn 40, I want to have written a book" with "Before I turn 40, I want to write a book", I'd say that there's a slight difference in perspective.  In the first, you're imagining being in your forties, looking back, *having written* a book.

Answer (score 1):

*Before I turn 40, I want to **have** written a book.*

That means I want to have that job/accomplishment **behind me, completed,** by that time.

You are **looking back in time, at /accomplishments/achievements/**. Your other sentence looks forward in time, shows projects still to come.

Comment: They're closely related, though, because in order to have written a book, you first have to write a book.